# Resume previous instance and state of activity

Tags: android

I have two activities in my project -- `MainActivity` and `ChildActivity`, and `MainActivity` has a button to start `ChildActivity`. I want the button to start a new `ChildActivity` if the user hasn't already opened one before, and an old instance of `ChildActivity` if it has already been opened before (thus saving its previous state, similar to how `onBackPressed()` resumes the previous activity on the stack with its original state).

I have tried implementing this by adding `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)` in `MainActivity` when making the `intent` to call `ChildActivity`, and also by changing the `AndroidManifest.xml` file so that the `ChildActivity` only ever has a single instance like so: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`.

However, none of these solutions work because a new `ChildActivity` gets produced every time I click the button in `MainActivity`.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a diagram to show how you expect the stack to look and how you expect to navigate back through the stack when the back button is pressed. eg. MainActivity = M, and ChildActivity = C, 1,2,3 = new instance.  M->C1->C2->C3? or M->C1->M->C2->M->C3? I have no idea what this is supposed to mean:: "start a new ChildActivity if the user hasn't already...an old instance of ChildActivity if it has already been opened".

Comment: M->C1->M->C1->M->C1, etc. So basically, I only want one instance of ChildActivity and every time C1 is opened, it should have the same state as before. That is, M->C1(with a certain state)->M->C1(with same state as the previous C1). The stack would look like [this](https://imgur.com/3qPqZI0). Note that in the 3rd stack, I have drawn C1 in the bottom to represent that I don't want the original instance of ChildActivity to be killed - because then the app would have to generate a new instance of ChildActivity

Comment: Ok. The image you provided in the link makes more sense. You want to go back and forth but not create a completely new instance of the `ChildActivity`.

Comment: Yes, do you know where I'm going wrong? I thought this could be accomplished just by adding the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to the intent when starting `ChildActivity`, however that still seems to make a new instance of `ChildActivity` every time the button is pressed

Comment: I suggest you work with `startActivityForResults` and `onActivityResult` passing data to the `ChildActivity` with `Intent` in combination with `putExtra` to pass the data and update it each time you return to the `MainActivity` in the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `SharedPreferences` in the `ChildActivity`. You could save the state in `SharedPreferences` and reload the data each time you reopen the `ChildActivity`.  You will need to get rid of all `SharedPreferences` when you kill the app...otherwise you will load the last sessions data the next time the `ChildActivity` is opened

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And if I want to pass an object (let's say a `pendingIntent`) back and forth between `ChildActivity` and `MainActivity`, and I am not able to make the object implement `Parcelable`, would you suggest I use GSON to convert it to a String and then pass it?

Comment: Yes, I have seen developers use JSON or GSON to pass data. But, I'm not sure you can pass a `PendingIntent` in an `Intent` extra. I don't really understand why you would need to, but you might have a special case I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you!